# i3 Window Manager doesn't allow full screen videos on two monitors

Tags: debian, window-manager, multi-monitor, i3

I'm currently using i3 Window Manager on Debian Wheezy, and as soon as I open a video in fullscreen (a YouTube video for example), and switch over to my second monitor, i3 reduces the video back to it's original size. Is there anyway of patching this?

Comment: It is almost certainly not i3 that does this, but the software providing the video (your browser, or Flash Player, probably).

Comment: Okay. I'm using Chromium, and I assume Flash. Might you have any suggestions?

Comment: You were right, the problem is with the flash player, not i3. My current solution is to use the addon MaximiseFlash and work on a better solution from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a hex hack for the libflashplayer.so around,
you can try http://simonmott.co.uk/blog/view/11 for a possible version.

the idea is to open libflashplayer.so or libgcflashplayer.so and search it for _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW and replace one of the letters, for example to _AET_ACTIVE_WINDOW

that will fix the issue of closing fullscreen flash when losing focus

Comment: Thanks, yeah! It works on most flash players, but after observing "sudo atop" when using multimonitor fullscreen flash, the cpu usage for iceweasel goes through the roof.

Comment: If CPU usage is your concern, I would recommend to use VLC to play the Flash videos. As CPU usage in general and GPU usage in particular seems to be flawed in flash, not only in ubuntu. There is a neat script that allows you to open the videos currently cached by flash in another player - for example VLC. As a bonus you get VLC postprocessing and advanced video settings to improve your quality, and you can change the audio delay when videos are out of sync. and more...

Comment: Check out http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/play-youtube-videos-without-flash-from.html for a neat tutorial for that Or google play youtube videos without flash. the title is misleading because it works on all flash videos.